# Transpose solution to non-homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ is an nxn real matrix and $A^t$ its transpose. Is it the case that if $Ax=0$ has a non-trivial solution that $A^tx=0$ has a non-trivial solution?

My guess is yes, mainly because the rank of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A^t$ but could someone explain it a little?

Comment: But may I ask why $Ax=0$ is a "non-homogeneous system"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. $Ax=0$ has non-trivial solutions iff $\text{rank}(A)<m$ where $m$ is the number of columns of $A$. Here $A$ is square, $m=n$, which is also the case for $A^t$.